# Javascript Variable not passing through ocanvas function and for loop

Tags: javascript, scope, ocanvas

I'm having an issue with a variable not being passed through an ocanvas function.  it appears that the variable is changing inside the function but isn't making it outside the function.  here is my code:

```
                sonicSpeed2 = 0;
                sonicState2 = 0;

                canvas.bind("keypress", function () {
                    var keys = canvas.keyboard.getKeysDown();
                    var x;

                    sonicSpeed2 = 4;

                    for (x = keys.length; x > 0; x--) {
                        if (keys[x-1] == 16 && keys.length > 1) {
                            sonicSpeed2 = 15;
                            sonicState2 = 2;
                        }
                        if (keys[x-1] == 65) {
                            sonicState2 = 1;
                            sonicDirection2a = false;
                        }
                        if (keys[x-1] == 68) {
                            sonicState2 = 1;
                            sonicDirection2a = true;
                        }
                        if (keys[x-1] == 87) {
                            sonicState2 = 1;
                            sonicDirection2b = false;
                        }
                        if (keys[x-1] == 83) {
                            sonicState2 = 1;
                            sonicDirection2b = true;
                        }
                    }
                });

                if (sonicDirection2a == false) {
                    nullObject2.x -= sonicSpeed2;
                }
                else if (sonicDirection2a == true) {
                    nullObject2.x += sonicSpeed2;
                }

                if (sonicDirection2b == false) {
                    nullObject2.y -= sonicSpeed2;
                }
                else if (sonicDirection2b == true) {
                    nullObject2.y += sonicSpeed2;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event handler is executed at an undetermined time in the future. *Binding* the event handler, which is what you are doing with `canvas.bind("keypress", ...)` does not executed the function. What comes *after* that is executed immediately.

If you want to do something in response to the event it has to be in or executed from the event handler.

See [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) for reference.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I got it working by placing 
     sonicSpeed2 = 0;
     sonicState2 = 0;
after the movement code.  I believe I understand how it works now, the keyboard input function will be rendered last in the loop, is that correct?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by that. My point was that the `if` statements after the event handler are executed before the event handler is executed. I.e. `nullObject2.x -= sonicSpeed2;` will never see the new values (which I assume is what you want). You'd have to put those `if` statements inside the handler as well.